# Postgresql select distinct

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I'm with a problem on postgresql select.

This query works fine:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(COLUMN_A || ' - ' || COLUMN_B),
    COLUMN_A,
    COLUMN_B
FROM
    TABLE_A
```

But, when I include a new colmun on select like that:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(COLUMN_A || ' - ' || COLUMN_B),
    COLUMN_A,
    COLUMN_B,
    COLUMN_C
FROM
    TABLE_A
```

The number of result grow's up, and the column with DISTINCT has repeated on result set.

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. Using `distinct (a), b` is the same as 
`distinct a, b` or `distinct a, (b)`. You simply put the columns between parentheses (which isn't such a good idea to begin with because that creates an anonymous record in Postgres).

In Postgres you can use `distinct on ()` for what you are trying to do (at least I think that's what you are trying to do):

```
SELECT distinct on (column_a, column_b) 
       COLUMN_A || ' - ' || COLUMN_B, 
       COLUMN_A,
       COLUMN_B
FROM TABLE_A
order by column_a, column_b
```

The above will only work in Postgres. If you are looking for a portable version based on the SQL standard, you can use a window function for this:

```
select column_a, column_b, column_c
from (
   select column_a, column_b, column_c, 
          row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b order by something) as rn
   from table_a
) t
where rn = 1;
```

The `order by something` is needed to pick one of the duplicate rows.